# JFace TableViewer: filling the table with contents

Tags: swt, jface, tableviewer

I am trying to work out how JFace's structural elements work. I made the following simple interface:

```java
protected Control createContents(Composite parent)
{
    Composite container = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    container.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));

    TableViewer tableViewer = new TableViewer(container, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
    table = tableViewer.getTable();
    table.setLinesVisible(true);
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);

    tableViewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());
    tableViewer.setInput(new String[][]{{"1", "2", "3"},{"1", "2", "3"},{"1", "2", "3"}});

    TableViewerColumn tableViewerColumn = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, SWT.NONE);
    TableColumn tblclmnTest = tableViewerColumn.getColumn();
    tblclmnTest.setWidth(58);
    tblclmnTest.setText("Test1");
    tableViewerColumn.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider()
    {
        @Override
        public String getText(Object element)
        {
            return super.getText(((String[])element)[0]);
        }
    });

    TableViewerColumn tableViewerColumn2 = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, SWT.NONE);
    TableColumn tblclmnTest2 = tableViewerColumn2.getColumn();
    tblclmnTest2.setWidth(58);
    tblclmnTest2.setText("Test2");
    tableViewerColumn2.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider()
    {
        @Override
        public String getText(Object element)
        {
            return super.getText(((String[])element)[1]);
        }
    });

    TableViewerColumn tableViewerColumn3 = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, SWT.NONE);
    TableColumn tblclmnTest3 = tableViewerColumn3.getColumn();
    tblclmnTest3.setWidth(58);
    tblclmnTest3.setText("Test3");
    tableViewerColumn3.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider()
    {
        @Override
        public String getText(Object element)
        {
            return super.getText(((String[])element)[2]);
        }
    });

    return container;
}
```

I did everything similar to the [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJFaceTable/article.html) but the problem is: `getText()` methods aren't being called. I figured it out by inserting `System.out.prinln` into them. And the result doesn't look like it supposed to look:

[image: screenshot]

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `tableViewer.setInput` before setting up the table columns - you must do the `setInput` after all the columns are defined.

Comment: Thanks! Accidentally I just figured it out myself :) The other way around would be to call `tableViewer.refresh()` after setting the label providers. I'd like to know what content provider is used if I am invoking `setInput` without any content providers like in my question. It is probably the [plain implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.6/org.eclipse/jface/3.6.0/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/LabelProvider.java?av=f) of ILabelProvider, but where I can see it in the api?

Comment: I went down through several inheritance levels of the class TableViewer but couldn't find anything where default lable provider is set.

Comment: Things based on `ColumnViewer` work on column label providers and don't set a single label provider. If you use a single label provider then internal column label providers are constructed - see `CellLabelProvider` and `TableColumnViewerLabelProvider`. The numerous different legacy label providers make all this very messy.